# How to display multiple consoles and Projects in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea, is there a way to show 2 consoles side by side at the same time? 
And can it Idea open multiple projects in one window? 
Below picture of Eclipse is what I want. 
Thanks!

[screenshot of multiple consoles and Projects in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8jM.png)

Comment: Have you tried this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206896435-Multiple-consoles-next-to-each-other-

Comment: Yes, actually that's the closest answer I've found, and tried to do it that way, but not working. Anyway, just got answer from Jetbrain that it is "No, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it."

Answer (score 0):

please check Migrating From Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html